# Can I use double for loops to sort a List?

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

What is the difference between using `Collections.sort()` method and my implementation of sorting a `List`? Which is faster?

```
public static void listSortingDoubleForLoop(List<Integer> list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(j)) > 0) {
                Collections.swap(list, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you measure it?

Comment: Can you paste here .sort() results and your listSortingDoubleForLoop results on dfifferent list sizes?

Comment: This takes n²/2 steps, for n=1000: **500,000**. `sort` would do for the worst case in the order of n ²log n is **10,000**, in the best case it might even be **1,000**.

Answer (score 3):

Your two nested for loops take quadratic running time (i.e. O(n<sup>2</sup>)).

The JDK implementations of `Collections.sort()` use more efficient O(nlogn) sort algorithms.

Here are, for example, the implementation notes for JDK 8:

> This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort that requires **far fewer than n lg(n)** comparisons when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the **performance of a traditional mergesort** when the input array is randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the implementation requires approximately n comparisons.

The performance of traditional merge sort is O(nlog(n)).